# Move jfxrt to lib/ext for OSGI purposes

Tags: java, osgi, javafx, bndtools

It has been suggested that part of the solution of the problem with javafx classloading and osgi is to move jfxrt to the Java installation lib/ext directory so that it is loaded when the JVM starts.

If this is done in a private install of Java the javafx classes are available at design time but are not found at run time when a javafx bundle is installed.

Is it possible that this can be made to work?

I am using felix and bndtools in eclipse as dev environment on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the bundles that are using javafx packages must import them with `Import-Package`.

Next you need to get the system bundle to export the packages. By default the system bundle only exports the standard JRE packages plus the OSGi framework packages; you can extend this by setting the property `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`. Since you are using Bndtools (good!) you can set the property as follows:

```
-runsystempackages: javafx.foo,javafx.bar...
```

Comment: Using bndtools, how are the Import-Package details entered?

Comment: If they are entered in the source and resolve is run all the detail in the run tab disappears. The only other option seems to be to add a bundle to the run requirements and how is this done with the jfxrt jar?

Comment: The import package statement is added to the bundle automatically, based on the packages that you actually use in your code. I.e. if you use package `org.foo` in your code, bnd will add `org.foo` to your `Import-Package`. You should not write `Import-Package` manually.

Comment: Regarding your second comment: jfxrt.jar shouldn't be added as a bundle because (a) Oracle intended it to be uses as part of the extension library of the JRE itself, and (b) it's not a bundle anyway. Since it's already part of the JRE, you just need to give your OSGi bundles access to it using the `-runsystempackages` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently released a first Early Access version of [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org), a modular Rich Client Platform for JavaFX based on OSGi and Maven (POM-first).

You can read more about it here:
http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/12/drombler-fx-building-modular-javafx.html

Getting Startet:
http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted

The generated output is explained here:
http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted#drombler-fx-sample-application-the-binaries-explained

(I didn't have to move any JavaFX JARs.)